# How can I solve this error "Reverse for 'resume-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['userapp/view/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/\\Z']"?

Tags: django, crud

I'm trying to delete from my database but I'm getting the error "Reverse for 'resume-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['userapp/view/(?P[^/]+)/\Z']". How do I resolve this error ?

views.py

```
def delete_view_experience(request, experience_id):
    
    experience_instance=get_object_or_404(Experience, id=experience_id)
  
    if experience_instance:
        experience_instance.delete()
        messages.success(request,"Information Deleted Successfully")
        
    return redirect('resume-detail')
```

urls.py

```
 path('userapp/view/<str:slug>/', user_views.resume_detail, name='resume-detail'),
    path('delete-experience/<int:experience_id>/', user_views.delete_view_experience, name='delete_experience'),
```

models.py

```
class Experience(models.Model):

    company = models.CharField(null = True, max_length=200)
    position = models.CharField(null = True, max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date  = models.DateField()
    experience = models.TextField()
    skills = models.TextField()
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} at {}'.format(self.position, self.company)
```

error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Muhumuza-Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Muhumuza-Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response     
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Muhumuza-Ivan\Desktop\JobPortal\userapp\views.py", line 219, in delete_view_education
    return redirect('resume-detail')
  File "C:\Users\Muhumuza-Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 48, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Muhumuza-Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 145, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Muhumuza-Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Muhumuza-Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 802, in _reverse_with_prefix  
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'resume-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['userapp/view/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/\\Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line `obj  = get_object_or_404(experience=experience_instance)` you are calling `get_object_or_404` again, this time without passing a class.

Comment: I've added the class Experience but it raises another error "No Experience matches the given query."

Comment: The rest of the arguments you pass to get_object_or_404 must be in the format accepted by the get() function of the model manager for your Experience class. (see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) Usually, one would pass something like pk=pk or id=id like you did in the first call. Unless you were using a custom implementation of get (unlikely and probably not useful), you can't pass an entire 'experience' object. I'm also not quite sure what your intention is – how does the result which you *desire* from the first line differ from the second line?

Comment: Forget the second line. I intend to delete experience from the database. I guess am frustrated cause I can't figure out what I'm doing here

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I believe obj & experience are complete duplicates of experience_instance can be disposed of, along with most of the code around them. Maybe it becomes clear after a break what logic to implement precisely. :)

Comment: I've made adjustments to the Views.py and get this error now "Reverse for 'resume-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['userapp/view/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/\\Z']" However when I go back a page the instance is deleted. Any ideas ?

Comment: Yes: The deletion runs fine, but the redirect is incorrect. In the line `return redirect('resume-detail')`, just the name 'resume-detail' of the route is not enough: `redirect` in this case calls `reverse`, and `reverse` needs a value for `slug` in this case. Please look up the documentation for `redirect` and `reverse`, e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/